# Вытащить из input и textarea значение всех элементов в массив, при нажатии на кнопку «Добавить»

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<div data-field="blockHttp" class="field block-http-palette-field is-in- 
 action">

   <input type="text" name="url" placeholder="http://www.wer.ru/">

<div class="http-block">
                <input type="text" name="param-title" 
 placeholder="название">
                <input type="text" name="param-value" 
placeholder="значение">
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete-http- 
 block">x</button>
            </div>

 <button class="btn btn-blue add-http-block margin-top-5">+ 
Добавить</button>


 <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-

 container--below" dir="ltr" style="width: 912px;"><span class="selection">

<span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" 

 aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" 

tabindex="0" aria-owns="select2-f8jf-results" aria-labelledby="select2-f8jf-

 container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-f8jf- 

 container" title="POST">POST</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow"

role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span 

class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>

<textarea class="form-control autosize" data-autosize-on="true"

style="overflow: hidden; resize: none; word-wrap: break-word; height: 

   250px;"></textarea>

<button class="control-button" data-action="apply2">Добавить</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

> Вытащить из input и textarea значение всех элементов в массив, при нажатии на кнопку «Добавить»

Есть такая функция в *jQuery* `serializeArray`, практичеки под ваш запрос.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Не отсылать на сервер
    var data = $(this).serializeArray(); // Все данные из формы

    console.log(data);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div data-field="blockHttp" class="field block-http-palette-field is-in- 
 action">

    <input type="text" name="url" placeholder="http://www.wer.ru/">

    <div class="http-block">
      <input type="text" name="param-title" placeholder="название">
      <input type="text" name="param-value" placeholder="значение">
      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete-http- 
 block">x</button>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-blue add-http-block margin-top-5">+ 
Добавить</button>


    <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-

 container--below" dir="ltr" style="width: 912px;"><span class="selection">

<span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" 

 aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" 

tabindex="0" aria-owns="select2-f8jf-results" aria-labelledby="select2-f8jf-

 container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-f8jf- 

 container" title="POST">POST</span>
    <span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span>
    </span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>

    <textarea class="form-control autosize" data-autosize-on="true" name="msg" style="overflow: hidden; resize: none; word-wrap: break-word; height: 250px;"></textarea>
</form>
```

---

**UPD:** Без элемента `form`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

   $('button').on('click', function () { 
     var data = $(':input').serializeArray(); 
     // Возможно понадобится отфильтровать кнопки тогда используете это:
     // :input:not([type=button]):not([type=submit]):not([type=reset])
      console.log(data)
   })
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-field="blockHttp" class="field block-http-palette-field is-in- 
 action">

   <input type="text" name="url" placeholder="http://www.wer.ru/">

<div class="http-block">
                <input type="text" name="param-title" 
 placeholder="название">
                <input type="text" name="param-value" 
placeholder="значение">
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete-http- 
 block">x</button>
            </div>

 <button class="btn btn-blue add-http-block margin-top-5">+ 
Добавить</button>


 <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-

 container--below" dir="ltr" style="width: 912px;"><span class="selection">

<span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" 

 aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" 

tabindex="0" aria-owns="select2-f8jf-results" aria-labelledby="select2-f8jf-

 container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-f8jf- 

 container" title="POST">POST</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow"

role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span 

class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
<!-------- Добавленно name="msg" name обязательно!!! -------->
<textarea class="form-control autosize" name="msg" data-autosize-on="true"

style="overflow: hidden; resize: none; word-wrap: break-word; height: 

   250px;"></textarea>

<button class="control-button" data-action="apply2">Добавить</button>
```

Comment: да, с тегом форм и у меня выходило, а если тег форм убрать, а оставить одну обертку див с именем класса ?

Comment: @oleja а вы для какой цели собираете эти данные?

Comment: есть графические объекты, которые строятся в дерево, графические объекты генерируются в html с помощью библиотеки rappid.js, к сожалению он строит их только внутри классов div, а не внутри форм. Таких объетов много и нужно вывести все заполненные свойства, внутри объектов.

Comment: @oleja добавил вариант без элемента `form`.